# Python Calculator Program Crashes When Invalid Equation Entered

Tags: python, input, calculator

I am having this problem about a python calculator that I made. I am fairly new at python so please do not be too critical of me. I made it so it does not crash when equations like these are entered: 8*d, 8/0, dajf. However, when the user enters something such as: /7, *e, or *6. It crashes. How can you prevent it from crashing when an invalid equation like that is entered? Let say, it will just respond with "WARNING: Invalid Equation"

My current code:

```
valid_chars = "0123456789-+/* \n";
while True:
    x = "x="
    y = input(" >> ")
     x += y
     if any(c not in valid_chars for c in y):
         print("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
         continue
     try:
         exec(x)
     except ZeroDivisionError:
         print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
     else:
    print(x)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter invalid input, the actual exception raised is `SyntaxError`

```
 >> -8*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 19, in <module>
    exec(x)
  File "<string>", line 1
    x=-8*
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, you can simply trap `SyntaxError` as well, like this

```
 try:
     exec(x)
 except (ZeroDivisionError, SyntaxError):
     print ("WARNING: Invalid Equation")
 else:
     print(x)
```

Comment: oh, by using the second part of your answer, I can then basically fix all of my errors right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a calculator on Python. When I came to writing the part involving division I simply wrote:

```
   if n2 == 0: //dividing by zero isn't possible
    divbyzeroerror = 1
  else:
    answer = n1 / n2
  if choice == ("a"):
answer = n1 + n2
if choice == ("s"):
answer = n1 - n2

    if(divbyzeroerror == 1): //if n2 is inputted as zero, the divbyzeroerror   variable becomes 1.  
    print("error, cannot divide by zero") //if n2 is a zero and therefore divbyzeroerror = 1, then you can get the program to print an error.
else:
print (answer)
```